# mouseenter only one DIV and not all of the same class

Tags: html, jquery

I have several divs with the same class (`.slider`).

I want to do a `slideUp` and `slideDown` on the div or I move the mouse only,

The problem here is that the function works for all the divs that have the class and not only the one where I put the mouse.

Any idea please ?

```js
$('.container').on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".slider").slideDown();
  });
  $('.container').on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".slider").slideUp("400");
  });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
}
.image{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000000;
}
.slider {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -50px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
  </div>
  <br/ >
  <div class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="text">Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you have several `<div class="slider">` inside `<div class="container">` how do you know which one should be affected? Also *on the div or I move the mouse only,* Huh?

Comment: Try $(this).find(".slider").slideDown() instead of $(".slider").slideDown();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example: 
*I wrapped your `.slider & .image` in a new div with the class `.block`. 

In the JS I'm then checking if a `.block` has been mouseenter/mouseleave, if that's the case, I make sure to slideIn/Out the respectiv `.slider`* with `$(this).find('slider')`.

```js
$('.block').on("mouseenter", function() {
  $(this).find('.slider').slideDown();
});

$('.block').on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).find('.slider').slideUp("400");
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
}

.block {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.image {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000000;
}

.slider {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: -50px 0 0 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="block">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="text">Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```